# What is the first order approximation?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Picture below is from  *Oh, Yong-Geun*, [**Stability of semiclassical bound states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations with potentials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01218621), Commun. Math. Phys. 121, No. 1, 11-33 (1989). [ZBL0693.35132](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0693.35132).

I don't know how to get $\langle u_h, u\rangle =0$. What I do :

In fact , $\Psi(x,t)= u_h + u +iv$, I want to use $\frac{d}{dt}\int |\Psi(x,t)|dx=0$ to show (24), but seemly, it is useless.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: A first order approximation is one whose taylor series is identical for all terms of power 0 or 1. Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in your post to be able to interpret this. However, you seem to be confused. (24) is an initial condition that the author is considering in place of (19). It is not something derivable from (19) (though the first-order claim does indicate that they should be related). It is not necessary to derive $\langle u_h, u\rangle = 0$ from something before. Instead it is a condition that the author is imposing on the problem at this point.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I agree with you, but at last, $\langle u_h,u \rangle =0$ is vanish (in the result of stability), I don't know how to do it.